# No se pudo encontrar o cargar la clase principal

Tags: java

Tengo un archivo MyFirstProgram.java que contiene dos clases. Acabo de modificar el Path y intenté probar el archivo con `java` y `javac`.

```
public class Point{
    private int x;
    private int y;
}

public class MyFirstProgram{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello ! World :)");
    }
}
```

Sin embargo me devuelve:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien>java MyFirstProgram.java
Error: Could not find or load main class MyFirstProgram.java

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien>javac MyFirstProgram.java
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Aqui esta el Path:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo funciona cuando llamo para javac directamente en la carpeta:

```
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin\javac" MyFirstProgram.java

C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien>java MyFirstProgram
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MyFirstProgram has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Pero hay un problema con `java`.

Comment: Quítale el `.java`.   Escribe esto `java MyFirstProgram`

Comment: @DiegoLoL Tiengo tambien `Error: Could not find or load main class MyFirstProgram`

Comment: Recuerda que primero tienes que compilar con `javac` y buscará el .java.  Y luego `java` que buscará el .class

Comment: @DiegoLoL Si, y parece que `javac` no es reconocido como un comando interno o externo, programa operable o archivo por lotes mientras que lo anadi en el path.

Comment: También en un archivo sólo puede haber una única clase con el modificador public, en este caso será el que contiene el main

Comment: @DiegoLoL Ok, he eliminado el punto de clase. Pero ¿Cómo llamo a javac directamente, sin usar `C:// ...` ? También agregué el nuevo error que aparece. Parece un problema de versión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que tienes dos jdk en las variables del sistema `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` y `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\bin` por lo que el proceso de compilación lo haces con una versión y la ejecución con otra. Elimina una de las dos versiones de las variables de entorno.

Además tienes dos clases en el fichero `MyFirstProgram.java`, para que funcione correctamente solo la clase que tiene el nombre del fichero puede ser publica, la otra u otras deben tener el modificador de acceso package o por defecto.

```
class Point{
    private int x;
    private int y;
}

public class MyFirstProgram{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Hello ! World :)");
    }
}
```